# Show that $\textbf{a}^T\textbf{Y}$ is the best linear unbiased estimator of $E(\textbf{a}^T\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X})$ if certain conditions hold

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, least-squares

I believe this is very similar to the proof of the Gauss-Markov theorem. Suppose $E[\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X}] = \textbf{X} \boldsymbol\beta$ and $var(\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X}) = \sigma^2\textbf{I}_n$. How can I show that $\textbf{a}^T\textbf{Y}$ is BLUE(best linear unbiased estimator) of $E(\textbf{a}^T\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X})$ if and only if $cov(\textbf{a}^T\textbf{Y}, \textbf{b}^T\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X}) = 0$ for all $b$ such that $E(\textbf{b}^T\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X}) = 0$.

This is what I have tried:
suppose $b^TY$ is a linear unbiased estimator for $E[a^TY|X] = a^TE[Y|X] = a^TX\beta$, then
$$E[b^TY|X] = b^TE[Y|X] = b^TX\beta = a^TX\beta$$
\begin{equation}\Rightarrow (b^T-a^T)X\beta = 0 ----------------------------- (1)\end{equation}

Want to show that
$$Var(b^TY|X) \geq Var(a^TY|X)$$
Note that
\begin{align*} Var(b^TY|X) = var[(b^TY-a^TY) + a^TY | X] = Var(b^TY-a^TY|X) + Var(a^TY|X) + 2Cov(b^TY-a^TY, a^TY|X) \end{align*}
It suffices to show that $2Cov(b^TY-a^TY, a^TY) = 0$
\begin{align} 2Cov(b^TY-a^TY, a^TY|X) = 2Cov(b^TY, a^TY|X) - 2Cov(a^TY, a^TY|X) = 0 ------ (2)\end{align}

I am not sure how to prove the if and only if statement using (1)(2)

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks all in advance.

Comment: $\mathbb E(\textbf{b}^\mathsf T\textbf{Y}|\textbf{X}) $ has to be $0?$